# How to make the ScheduledTaskAgent start as soon as the app is installed?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to make the ScheduledTaskAgent start as soon as the app is installed? I have seen a property LaunchOnBoot when registering the service in WMManifest file. I set it to True and does not seem to serve the purpose. Any ideas?

This is for updating a tile (Primary Tile). The tile need to be updated as soon as the user pins the app to the home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot to it. Your app must run when registering a ScheduledTaskAgent .

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for debugging you may use [ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Otherwise you can not. But the real question then would be why you need it other than debugging?

Comment: I do not need for debugging, @deeiip. This is for updating a tile (Primary Tile). The tile need to be updated as soon as the user pins the app to the home screen. I have edited my post.

Comment: you can update the tile without using background task. Actually you really dont have any control over how and when the background task will run (even you can not be sure that it'll run at all)

Comment: How do I do that, @deeiip? For ex, the user installs my app, then immediately pins it on the home screen. The user does not even open the app.